# How to install IQ driver to connect to oracle through LINQPAD

Tags: .net, linq, oracle11g, linqpad

Im using Linqpad v4.4
I need to connect to Oracle 11g DB. I've found IQ driver could do that & downloaded it but am not able install. I've tried multiple ways

1. Add connections->View more drivers -> Browse -> (I can file type as LINQPAD DRIVERS) Can't get IQ Driver option anyways.
2. Double click -> No use

Plz help on connecting to Oracle DB

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had that same problem. It was because I was behind a corporate firewall.

The solution for it, was downloading the LPX file for the driver and did a manual install.

On the second line of the page where you see all available drivers for LinqPad, you have "Blocked by a proxy or firewall? Click here to download these drivers from a web browser."

If you click the link your browser will open "http://www.linqpad.net/RichClient/DataContextDrivers.aspx"

There you can Download the Driver "Download & Enable Driver", and you get a zip file. Rename the Zip to LPX. After that, You can then, use the option in the LinqPad window, to choose the drivers, at the bottom you have "Or, browse to a .LPX file". Click the Browse button and choose the downloaded file, now with LPX extension. And the driver will be installed.

Comment: This worked too, once I re-read your answer and didn't gloss over "Rename the Zip to LPX" part.

Comment: Btw, the "Option in the LinqPad window" can be found by clicking Add connection -> View more drivers. Took me few minutes to find it :(